# Load stored width position of vertical sidebar after page reload

Tags: javascript, sidebar

How to set and use the local storage data of the left sidebar width after resizing the sidebar and reloading the page?

I have created a local storage data and retrieve it using the codes below but after reloading the page the resized sidebar is going back to its default width. It should have an "onload" event attribute?

Here is the link where I get the codes https://htmldom.dev/create-resizable-split-views/

Credit to: htmldom.dev for sharing this code

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    // Query the element
    const resize = document.getElementById('dragMe');
    const leftSide = resize.previousElementSibling;
    const rightSide = resize.nextElementSibling;

    // The current position of mouse
    let x = 0;
    let y = 0;
    let leftWidth = 0;

    // Handle the mousedown event
    // that's triggered when user drags the resize
    const mouseDownHandler = function (e) {
        // Get the current mouse position
        x = e.clientX;
        y = e.clientY;
        leftWidth = leftSide.getBoundingClientRect().width;

        // Attach the listeners to `document`
        document.addEventListener('mousemove', mouseMoveHandler);
        document.addEventListener('mouseup', mouseUpHandler);
    };

    const mouseMoveHandler = function (e) {
        // How far the mouse has been moved
        const dx = e.clientX - x;
        const dy = e.clientY - y;

        // Set a new left width and saving to local storage
        const newLeftWidth = ((leftWidth + dx) * 100) / resize.parentNode.getBoundingClientRect().width;
        leftSide.style.width = `${newLeftWidth}%`;

        resize.style.cursor = 'col-resize';
        document.body.style.cursor = 'col-resize';

        leftSide.style.userSelect = 'none';
        leftSide.style.pointerEvents = 'none';

        localStorage.setItem('newLeftWidth', leftSide.style.width);
        const localNewLeftWidth = localStorage.getItem('newLeftWidth');
        leftSide.style.width = localNewLeftWidth;
        console.log('log:' + localNewLeftWidth);

        rightSide.style.userSelect = 'none';
        rightSide.style.pointerEvents = 'none';
    };

    const mouseUpHandler = function () {
        resize.style.removeProperty('cursor');
        document.body.style.removeProperty('cursor');

        leftSide.style.removeProperty('user-select');
        leftSide.style.removeProperty('pointer-events');

        rightSide.style.removeProperty('user-select');
        rightSide.style.removeProperty('pointer-events');

        // Remove the handlers of `mousemove` and `mouseup`
        document.removeEventListener('mousemove', mouseMoveHandler);
        document.removeEventListener('mouseup', mouseUpHandler);
    };

    // Attach the handler
    resize.addEventListener('mousedown', mouseDownHandler);
});
```

Comment: Please keep your edits to a minimum - if you need to add details or clarity, please make sure you edit your post once (or more only if required). Your current track of editing seems like you are trying to keep your question at the top of the home page "active" (16 of your edits at time of writing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to load the stored position when the page is loaded, you might want to use the `DOMContentLoaded` event:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  const localNewLeftWidth = localStorage.getItem('newLeftWidth');
  leftSide.style.width = `${localNewLeftWidth}%`;
  console.log('log: ' +`${localNewLeftWidth}%`);

  // Possibly load other stuff here 
});
```

Note that you have to add this event listener *outside* of your `mouseMoveHandler`.

You can learn more about the `DOMContentLoaded` event here: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event.